# new Vector<Object>(myOtherVector) : Clone or reference?

Tags: java, vector

My question is if this call will clone the content of the other vector into the new vector or if it will create references to the data in the other vector?

```
new Vector<Object>(myOtherVector);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector(java.util.Collection)

Comment: It's a copy of the references, so if you add/remove elements from `myOtherVector`, the changes won't be reflected in the new `Vector`, but if you modify the elements, both `Vector`s will see the changes (of the elements).  `Vector` is kind of consider deprecated and you should be using the `Collection` based classes (`List`/`ArrayList`/`LinkedList`) unless you have a particular use case for it

Comment: For primitives, it will copy each value in the new vector, for objects it will copy each reference, so the objects instance will be shared between the two vectors.

Comment: By the way: Don't use Vector.

Comment: @BackSlash: A `Vector` of primitives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i have any doubt like this, i use to make a simple example:

```
private static class MyClass {
        int id;
    public MyClass(int i) {
        id = i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "" + id;
    }

    public void setId(int i) {
        id = i;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector<MyClass> old = new Vector<MyClass>();

    old.add(new MyClass(1));
    old.add(new MyClass(2));
    old.add(new MyClass(3));
    Vector<MyClass> newVec = new Vector<MyClass>(old);
    old.get(0).setId(1000);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString("old "+old.toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString("newVec "+newVec.toArray()));
}
```

Result:

```
old [1000, 2, 3]
newVec [1000, 2, 3]
```

As you can see, the objects in the Vector are the same, it does not do a copy ob the object, just create a new reference to that instance.

Comment: How do you get primitive types into your `Vector`?

Comment: I dont undestand you.

Comment: A `Vector` can't contain primitives, so your comment about copying primitive types is a bit confusing.

Comment: This example doesn't show if elements are the same (by reference) or not (only equals because they are a clone). If you change the example adding objects to the list and comparing them with == it works. Otherwise not. This is not a right answer, also if the approach is very interesting.

Comment: I think this example desmostrates that the instances in the two vectors are the same, because if I change a property of an object in the first vector, i see the change in the seconds vector too.

Answer (score 2):

> Constructs a vector containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Here is the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java#Vector.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Collection%29) of that constructor. It's  copy of references to the passed elements

```
 public Vector(Collection<? extends E> c) {
167         elementData = c.toArray();
168         elementCount = elementData.length;
169         // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
170         if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
171             elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, elementCount, Object[].class);
172     }
```

Answer (score 2):

The specification you link to states

> *Constructs a vector containing the elements of the specified collection...*

In other words, the same elements will be placed in the new `Vector`, it will not create new copies.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the implementation of `Vector` constructor. So it is a copy of the original array with a reference to existing objects.

```
public Vector(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray();
    elementCount = elementData.length;
    // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
    if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, elementCount,  Object[].class);
}
```